# Is there a way to debug multithreaded applications in singletreaded mode in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

When I debug multithreaded .net applications I want the max degree of parallelism to be 1. I mean I want only one thread to run at a time.

In that way I wouldn't have to go through long tutorials about flagging threads, using parallel watch or learn how find out the ID of "my thread". All I am interested in is to debug multithreaded application in a singletreaded mode.

Is there any way of making Visual Studio work with one thread at a time?
Or make my .net application single threaded with a global setting?
Or a workaround, maybe set Windows 10 to run in singlethreaded mode? Be creative!

Comment: You're asking for suggestions, which means no one answer could ever be accepted as THE answer, which means the question not good fit for Stack Overflow. Having said that, here's a suggestion :). While debugging, open Threads window (Debug > Windows > Threads), select all threads you want to freeze, click Freeze Threads (Pause button in Threads window). Opposite of "freeze" is "thaw".

Comment: The problem with this idea is that you could miss whole classes of bugs that only occur *because* of multithreading. You'll have to learn the techniques anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to debug multithreaded applications in singletreaded
> mode in Visual Studio?

Just as **Dialecticus** suggested, you could try these:

**Suggestion**

**1)** Use **Threads Window**

- first, set a breakpoint at the entry of the main function
- start debugging and then enter **Debug**-->**Windows**-->**Threads**--> then right-click on the threads that you do not want to debug and then select **Freeze**. And note that you have to always click on `switch to thread`, every time something happens.
- You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-threads-window?view=vs-2019&redirectedfrom=MSDN) about using Threads Window.

**2)** you can try to follow [this document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/filter-breakpoints/) to set a new breakpoint about the specific single thread ID to debug it.

**3)** there is also a vs extension called [Debug Single Thread](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.DebugSingleThread). You can also use it.